# How well do AMD Raven Ridge APU's work with linux now?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amd-processor, amdgpu

I was thinking of buying an AMD Ryzen 3 2200G or an AMD Ryzen 5 2400G, but one thing that is a make or break is linux support. How well does the chip work now, because a while ago (6 months or so) it seemed like linux did not support the onboard graphics very well, but i have not seen anything recently about it. So if anyone knows how good the support is now that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: this question may sound opinion-based, but it actually can be answered with "hard facts" (graphics output ok? does video acceleration work? etc.). Maybe the title "Is Raven Ridge now fully supported by Linux" would have been better.

Answer (score 5):

We use 2 Raven Ridge at home. My wife: R3 2200G, Asus Prime B450M-A, 2x4 Ballistix 2666.

Me: R5 2400G, Asrock AB350M pro, 2x8 Ballistix 3000. Both under Ubuntu 18.04.1.
We are quite happy with these APU. We aren't gamers, those PC are used for photo editing, video and HTPC.

It wasn't too difficult to get stable systems... We had to:

- Change the kernels to Linux 4.18 (easy with [UKUU](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu)).
- Get the latest mesa with the Oibaff repository.
- Get the latest BIOS for the motherboards.

To install Ubuntu with a live USB, we had to add the option "nomodeset" to the Grub2 (to avoid a split screen).

With the Asrock, I still have some problems to start the PC, it needs sometimes a couple of tries. But when it starts, the system is rock solid. No problem what so ever with Asus.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4):

As of 23 Sept 18, I am running U1804 with only default updates on an Ryzen 5 2400G and Asus Prime B450M-PLUS M/B (latest BIOS) and it works well for normal non gaming use. There's some red lines in DMESG but seem to have no impact. Only change was to use VLC instead of Videos to play mp4's to avoid some freezing.
Likely later kernel/drivers will increase performance but at least its now working out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

I am using AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Gigabyte A320 chipset motherboard. After upgrading BIOS to F23 and kernel 4.19 beta-4, there are no boot issues, but random freeze is there. So I have decided not to use the System, as I am a programmer, system stability is of paramount importance. I have switched to my older system till Kernel 5.0 is released. I hope by then stability and random freezing will stop.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

I recently built a PC with an Asus Prime A320M-K motherboard, a Ryzen 3 2200G and 2x8GB Corsair 2400MHz RAM. After updating the BIOS to the most recent version, I installed Kubuntu 18.10 (it ships with kernel 4.18). I have not had any issues while web browsing or video streaming yet. There are no booting issues at the moment, except that the splash screen does not show.

**Update 2018-10-28**: It also works well without any problems using a 4K screen resolution. (Disclaimer: I did not test heavy 3D operations like gaming)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/891362)

Comment: @abu_bua I did not ask a new question. Instead I reported on my experiences with a specific hardware and software setup working quite well with a Ryzen 3 2200G. This information may be quite helpful for smileydude384.