# Ubuntu 18.10 installation fails: AMD-Vi Completion-Wait loop timed out [Ryzen 3 2200G + Radeon RX580]

Tags: system-installation, uefi, radeon, amd-processor, amdgpu

Ubuntu 18.10 fails during installation (Try Ubuntu or Install Ubuntu). Below some of the possible relevant traces, some on them repeating themselves several times:

```
AMD-Vi: Completion-Wait loop timed out
xhcdi_hcd Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 127
usb usb2-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
iommu ivhd0 IOTLB_INV_TIMEOUT
Kernel panic = not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

I have the following system:

```
ASUS Prime B450-M
Ryzen 3 2200G
Radeon RX580
BIOS 0409 2018/09/04 (latest available)
```

I've tried to use several kernel boot parameters (one at the time):

```
amdgpu.dc=1
amd_iommu=off
nomodeset
iommu=soft
```

Side notes: the USB max msg goes away if I unplug the small USB hub (mouse+kb) after I edited GRUB params. But the end result is the same. System works happily on Win10.

Is it a Ryzen 3 2200G compatibility issue? Or a Radeon RX580 compatibility issue? May I have better chance trying another distro for now, or is it kernel 4.x related?

Any info would be appreciated!

Sources:

- [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/85vav4/how_i_installed_ubuntu_1804_with_ryzen_2200g/dw1i2zy/)
- [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224265)
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070956/how-well-do-amd-raven-ridge-apus-work-with-linux-now/1078037)
- [SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469153/what-are-the-implication-of-iommu-soft) (not directly related)

**EDIT** Using a Debian daily mini.iso found [here](https://d-i.debian.org/daily-images/), I get the same messages but instead of kernel panic, the installer caries on. Until it reaches "detecting hardware". It stays there on 0% for a few minutes, then the screen goes blue (the installer blue, not a BSOD blue). After 10 minutes I decided to shut it down.

**EDIT2**

Some interesting findings. In the BIOS, the "Primary Video Display" setting does not seem to have any effect. The fact that a HDMI cable is connected to the MB causes the setting to become "IGFX". Connecting a DisplayPort on the RX580 causes the setting to be "PCIE". Changing the setting manually has no effect it seems.

Now, I managed to boot Ubuntu with "Try Ubuntu" option up to a working desktop, only in the following configuration:

- Avoid the UEFI USB entry in the boot menu (F8)
- HDMI cable connected to the MB (BIOS reads IGFX)

Looks like a UEFI + a RX580 compatibility issue.

That could have worked for me, except that I have a 4k screen, so HDMI is limited to 30Hz, that's a no-go for me. So at best, I could try to install Ubuntu w/o UEFI (any drawbacks?) and with the onboard APU, then maybe install the proprietary AMD drivers, to hopefully have a fully working system. Slightly reluctant to proceed under these conditions however (dual boot, don't want to risk the installer to freeze during partitioning or something and mess up Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 kernel 5.0.0-8 *and* BIOS update solved it. I thought ASUS Prime B450-M v.0409 08/04/2018 was the latest. This time I used EzUtility live internet update from the BIOS itself and I got upgraded to v.0604 12/07/2018. Although I have no idea if the kernel 5.0 is necessary for this setup to work.

I now have a fully working Ubuntu 4k 60Hz display.

Previously, my workaround was to connect the HDMI cable rather than the DisplayPort. The system would boot, but I was stuck at 30Hz if 4k (this hurts real bad), or stuck FHD if I wanted 60Hz. Fortunately this was not my primary setup.

Comment: Hi, I have the same error and a similar system (Ubuntu 18.04, Ryzen 3 2200G, ASUS Prime A320M-K mother board and nVidia GTX1650).

Comment: Did you update your BIOS? @BrunoA.

Answer (score 0):

@youri, yes I did. Updating the MB BIOS solved this problem (no need to update the linux kernel in my case) but it also created a new problem, so I recommend to be careful and do it at your own risk.

My computer could not POST after the update (original BIOS was v4029, dated 2018/11/30). After a lot of testing it was apparent that although my RAM was compatible with the older bios, it was not compatible with the newer ones (I tried v5207 and v5222). So I had to exchange the ram kit with another computer to make it work.