# Ubuntu can't boot, access rescue mode or reinstall

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, amd-graphics, amd-processor

Since a few days, I can't boot my computer on ubuntu, I can't even access rescue mode or boot on a liveusb to try to reinstall my os. Windows is booting fine however.

On a regular ubuntu boot some services fail to start and at some point, the boot process simply stops [image]

When I try to start rescue mode or boot with liveusb, I have other messages like `AMD-VI: Completion-Wait loop timed out` and `iommu ivhd0: Event logged [IOTLB_INV_TIMEOUT device=1b:00.0 address=0x40e596610]` or `Kernel panic - not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler`
[image] [image]

Computer specs :

- Motherboard: b350 PC MATE (bios up-to-date)
- CPU: Ryzen 5 2600X
- GPU: radeon RX 570
- Ubuntu 18.04.2

**edit**
I check my hardware (memtest, gpu/cpu stress test, SMART drive check) and nothing is wrong, I event tried another graphic card. I tried to boot with ubuntu 16.04 liveusb, same issue. I tried boot options `noapic`, `nolapic` without any success, with `acpi=off` I have the following screen [image]

I tried to boot with ubuntu daily build to have the latest kernel, but no luck.

I managed to access my terminal, update-grub didn't help, but when I typed `sudo apt update` I had `E: Error reading the CPU table`. /usr/share/dpkg/cputable was missing, I copied a version of the file I found in /snap/core18/941/usr/share/dpkg/cputable and now I have `E: Cannot find dpkg tuplet or triplet table`

Answer (score 1):

This **might be** couple of things:

- incompatibility of the linux kernel or drivers with your hardware, that happend i.e. after BIOS update
- indication of hardware failing, since you can't even boot from livecd.

Keep in mind that manufacturers mostly focus on windows boxes, that's why sometimes their hardware happens to be problematic with linux kernel.

If it comes to incompatibility you may want to try an older Ubuntu Live CD or - if it still won't boot - the newer one (like daily builds). By doing this you'll ensure whether it's specific to the kernel version, or not.

And when it comes to hardware problems, there are couple of boot options you may want to try to investigate this problem.

Please go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions to find more information about it.

I suggest trying `acpi=off`, `noapic` and `nolapic`. If at some point Ubuntu will boot with such options, it's a starting point for you to investigate it further, i.e. doing memtest, CPU and GPU stresstest and checking your hard drives SMARTs.

Comment: Thank you for your time unfortunately I tried what you suggested without any luck (I edited my post)

Comment: Unfortunately it's looks like an incompatibility, probably after drivers or BIOS being updated. Consider reporting this as a bug in linux kernel. Also please try to use daily builds of latest Ubuntu, with the latest kernel available. You can even try an another distro with rolling release model, so you got fresh kernel shipped with OS.

Comment: Also please read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089524/ubuntu-18-10-installation-fails-amd-vi-completion-wait-loop-timed-out-ryzen-3

Comment: the bios was updated AFTER the issue to try to solve it. I tried with a daily build as you suggested but it didn't help, same errors