# I was trying to ditch windows 10 for Ubuntu but cant due to my AB350-gaming board

Tags: system-installation

Not a good first time experience of Linux, it seems I cant even install it as it throws AMD-VI errors at me I have a Gigabyte AB350 Gaming Mobo with Ryzen 5 1600 2 x R9 280x GPUs 16 GB hyper x fury ram M.2 SSD I have been looking around and people are saying that you need to have a kernel above 4.10 I.E 4.10.1 but if im using the most recent Ubuntu ISO surely it has an up to date kernel?

Please free me from Microsoft and their bloated OS

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using?   The latest is Ubuntu 19.04 (from 2019-April) and uses a 5.0 kernel.  The latest LTS (18.04.2) with HWE kernel will give you 4.18, both of which are kernels greater than 4.10.  What are you trying to install?

Comment: I used LTS 18.04.2 and I thought that would be the case so I don't have a clue what the issue could be

Comment: also I flashed my bios today to r31

Comment: im using a USB image I created using ImageUSB by pasmark

Comment: Did you verify your install media?  (and check download integrity though install media check I consider more valuable). If it fails (because of download or write), the install shouldn't be expected to work (if it works, shouldn't be trusted anyway in my opinion).  *This should be done before you attempt install to avoid wasting time chasing errors that are the cause of faulty download or write*

Comment: it fails to install gets stuck in a AMD-vi error loop

Comment: have I checked the USB for bad sectors? yes

Comment: Possibly of use https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089524/ubuntu-18-10-installation-fails-amd-vi-completion-wait-loop-timed-out-ryzen-3  (ie. use the latest Ubuntu 19.04 is suggestion as answer)  and I didn't suggest checking for bad sectors; but using the check-media option which verifies the data written from ISO is correct/valid ensuring data on drive is correct.

Comment: I tested the USB an a VM install works fine

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't write the error down but its easy to recreate, I boot my system from the install media select Install Ubuntu then immediately it throws up AMD - Vi event logged timed out